# simple if/else not working..not sure why.(should be dumb-inly easy)

Tags: php

Ok so i have this image uploading thing im trying to add on this small app im trying to make...i stress ***trying*** lol(for my studies), and simply in this section, im trying to check for file type with a simple if/else.

i cut out the code to the part thats giving me problems.

so the html is this:

```
<form method="post" action="testUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table summary="practice" width="500">
        <tr>
            <td>load picture:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="screenshot" id="screenshot" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" action="submit"></td>
        </tr>
</table>


</form>
```

the php is this:

```
$screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
$picSize = $_FILES['screenshot']['size'];
$picType = $_FILES['screenshot']['type'];

if($screenshot && $picSize && $picType){
    if($picType == 'image/jpg' || $picType == 'image/pjpeg'){
            echo ' your pic type is jpg <br/>';
    } else {
        echo ' this pic type is not supported <br/>';
    }
}
```

when i run this, it always gives me the " this pic type is not supported."

the image im testing with is the correct size, type etc so not sure why its not giving me the first option.

when i test for size like so:

```
if ($picSize <9000){
        echo ' your pic size is within limits. <br/>';
    } else {
        echo ' pic is too big ';    
    }
```

it works so....i don't understand.

any ideas/suggestions etc. ill gladly accept.

thank you.

any ideas

Comment: Change the echo statement to something like:  `echo "'$picType' is not a supported image format.<br />";`.  That way you can see what the code actually thinks it is and account for it.

Comment: Please show `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: Can you echo out `$screenshot`, `$picSize` and `$picType` ? What are the results?

Comment: Echo `$picType` and see exactly what it is, maybe you're comparing it to the wrong thing.

Comment: Are you sure there is a value being stored in `$picType`?  `var_dump($picType)` or use your debugging tools and verify that there is an image type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have compared to the wrong mime type,
standard mime type for JPEG is `image/jpeg`,
which does not exist in your comparison clause

Comment: ahahaha lmfao nice! i had "jpg" not "jpeg".....i changed it, it works...sigh lol. ive been looking for a GOOD while...woulda never found it lol. thanks. and thanks to all others.

Answer (score 2):

Echo your pic type in the error, just to be sure what you are working with.

```
if($screenshot && $picSize && $picType){
    if($picType == 'image/jpg' || $picType == 'image/pjpeg'){
        echo ' your pic type is jpg <br/>';
    } else {
        echo ' this pic type is not supported (' . $picType . ')<br/>';
    }
}
```